Zookeeper data for solr-cloud is not saved after docker compose down
I have 3 solr-cloud containers (one of them for loading configurations, it stops right after executing the command) and one zookeeper.
services:
  solr1:
    image: solr
    container_name: solr-3z
    ports:
     - "8666:8666"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo123:2111
      - SOLR_PORT=8666
      - SOLR_HOST=192.168.1.110
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./solrdata:/var/solr

  solr2:
    image: solr
    container_name: solr-3z2
    ports:
     - "8667:8667"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo123:2111
      - SOLR_PORT=8667
      - SOLR_HOST=192.168.1.110
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./solrdata2:/var/solr

  solr3:
    image: solr
    container_name: solr-3z3
    environment:
      - ZK_HOST=zoo123:2111
    volumes:
      - ./configsets:/server/solr
    command: "bin/solr zk upconfig -n test -d /server/solr/test"



  zoo123:
    image: zookeeper
    container_name: zoo123
    hostname: zoo123
    ports:
      - 2111:2181
    volumes:
      - ./zookeeper-1:/var/lib/zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo123:2888:3888;2111
      ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST: "mntr,conf,ruok"

1 algorithm

executing the docker-compose up command
creating a collection
deleting 2 containers from solr-cloud
restarting the containers
Collections remain working

2 algorithm

executing the docker-compose up command
creating a collection
executing the docker command-compose down
running all the containers again
errors SolrCore test_shard1_replica_n4 in /var/solr/data/test_shard1_replica_n4 is not in cluster state.
collections are not available

How can I restore the solr-cloud to the docker compose down state?
